How to fix the "reactions.values(...).filter is not a function" error?
I'm trying to make a giveaway discord bot, but when I try to choose a random winner, it breaks and gives me this error:
            reactions = reactions.values().filter(user => user.id != "1268508879893958676")
                                           ^

TypeError: reactions.values(...).filter is not a function

It was breaking at first at the "values()" since I was putting "array()" instead, but when I fixed that, this error came in my way which I have no idea who to fix.
Here is my entire script /commands/giveaway.js

    const ms = require("ms");
    
    module.exports = {
        name: "giveaway",
        description: "Adds a giveaway.",
        async execute(message, args, Discord){
            let channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0])
            if (!channel) channel = message.channel;
            let winners = args[1]
            let time = args[2]
            let prize = args.slice(3).join(' ')
    
            time = ms(time)
    
            const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Giveaway!')
            .setDescription(`There is a new giveaway! React with "" to enter.\n\`Ends in:\`${ms(time, {
                long: true })}\nHosted by: ${message.author}`)
            .setColor("#ff6600")
            .setTimestamp(Date.now() + time)
    
            const e = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    
            e.react("")
    
            setTimeout(async () => {
    
                let reactions = await e.reactions.cache.get("").users.fetch()
                reactions = reactions.values().filter(user => user.id != "1268508879893958676") //<----------------- It breaks right here
    
                let w = []
    
                for (let i = 1; i <= winners; i++) {
                    w.push(reactions[Math.floor(Math.random() * reactions.length)])
                }
    
                message.channel.send(`${w.join(", ")} won the ${prize}!`)
            }, time)
        }
    }


Any idea on how to fix?

reactions.values() Returns an Iterable of a collection's values. You can use the native Collection.filter() method. If you ever need an array, use [...Collection.values()]

Simply try:
reactions = reactions.filter(user => user.id != "1268508879893958676")

and you'll also want to add .map to see the user in the message, so like this:
reactions = reactions.filter(user => user.id != "1268508879893958676").map(user => user.toString())

